# C# char/string Parsing issue

Tags: c#, string

I am a beginner programmer and am trying to create a basic calculator program. The calculator includes while loops and TryParsing because I want the program to write to the console a simple error message if the user decides to type incorrect input.

Everything works fine, except when I'm trying to create a variable for the Operator.

Currently I have it as a char variable named: char arithmeticOperator;

For the users' operator input part, my code is this:

```
while (decision == false)
{
    Console.Write("Choose an Operator (+ - * /) : ");
    decision = char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arithmeticOperator);

    if (decision == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not an Operator, try again...");
    }
}
```

This works for the number1, and number2 variables with no issue.

But I get an error during the 'if' statement part...

```
if (arithmeticOperator == '+')
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
```

arithmeticOperator has a red wavy line under saying "Use of unassigned local variable".

I looked this up and realized that char cannot be empty so I gave some value to char for testing; when the program runs, if I use valid arithmetic operators, the program works as it should; if I use anything else such as any other single character, the program restarts.

I tried using string instead, but you cannot TryParse a string and I can't figure out a solution for string.

I don't want an exception error so I avoided using Parse for string. I also want to let the user know if they inserted the wrong input by writing out "Invalid Input, try again" to the console.

I have 2 questions...

1. How can I apply Char specifically to ONLY use the arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /). If any other single character numbers or text letters are typed, it should display a console text error.
   Is this possible?
2. If I have a variable named: string choice = "YES";
   How can I use string so that if the user types something other than "YES", to display an error to the console without an exception error?

I don't need to use both char and string, but it would be good to know for future reference. I hope this made any sense, sorry for so much info.

Comment: You know C is not C# is not C++ is not Objective C is not C ...? Do not add tags for different languages!

Comment: Sorry about that didn't think it through. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that might work for you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char arithmeticOperator;
    bool decision = false;
    while (decision == false)
    {
        Console.Write("Choose an Operator (+ - * /) : ");
        char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arithmeticOperator);


        switch (arithmeticOperator)
        {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                decision = true;
                break;
            case '\0':
                Console.WriteLine("Error!!! Value is a string.");
                decision = false;
                break;
            default:
                decision = false;
                break;
        }

        if (decision == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not an Operator, try again...");
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- arithmeticOperator is declared as character only
- using `switch` to check between cases of operator (+ - * /)
- the `decision` variable is not dependent of the result of `char.TryParse()` instead on the `switch-case` conditional flow

For the *red wavy* warning, it is a condition where your variable `arithmeticOperator` wasn't assigned any value before it was used. In the sample code above, the declaration is empty ('\0' for character), but you will see that the `bool decision = false;` which makes the `while` loop always evaluated, hence `arithmeticOperator` will always have a value so it won't have any warnings Use of unassigned local variable).

1) For your first question to check if the character entered is a string. Yes it is possible to be checked via `\0` character. You can add this case:

```
case '\0':
    Console.WriteLine("Error!!! Value is a string.");
    decision = false;
    break;
```

2) For your second question, I'm not sure if I get it clearly but here is a code snippet, to accept `string` and get an answer `YES`, else have an error outputted:

```
string choice = "YES";
string answer = null;
while (true)
{
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if (answer.Trim().ToUpper().Equals(choice))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, say YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest staying away from switch statements, this could be re written more elegantly with the usage of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @AydinAdn, while I agree that `Dictionary` can be used to write it elegantly, the one who asks says that s/he is a beginner programmer. I would suggest that we start with the fundamentals.

Comment: I finally managed it, Thank you all very much!!! It works like it should it seems. I still need to fix the division part, for it to divide properly, and not divide by 0. But other than that it's working! How can I add code to replies? Can I add it as an "Answer" below?

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing more of the code, it sounds like you accidentally put your code to check for a '+' outside the code block where 'arithmeticOperator' is defined.  Either move that code inside the code block where arithmeticOperator is declared, or move the declaration out to have wider scope.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare your variables, each variable needs to be initialised first:

```
char arithmeticOperator = '\0'; // this is the default value for char
bool decision = false;
```

This makes each variable *something*, that can then be used later. If you *do not* initialise them (like so):

```
char arithmeticOperator;
```

then they cannot be assigned any new values, because they have no value that can be assigned to.

There are ways around this, as some of the other answers provide, but this is a good practice to get into - *Always* assign a variable a value *even if it is just* **`null`**

Comment: In C#, variables get initialized to their default values (null for reference types, varies for value types) if no initial value is specified.

Comment: A `char` can't be null in C#.

Comment: Agreed, a `char` is a value type, not a reference type. Its default value is '\0'. Per docs: "Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx